# How to convert CURL API to C# RestSharp

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am trying to convert a CURL API to C# RestSharp.
Below is the actual code

```
curl --location 'https://api.thePaymentGateway.io/v1/payout' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {{token}}' \
--header 'x-api-key: {{api-key}}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "ipn_callback_url": "https://thePaymentGateway.io",
    "withdrawals": [
        {
            "address": "TEmGwPeRTPiLFLVfBxXkSP91yc5GMNQhfS",
            "currency": "trx",
            "amount": 200,
            "ipn_callback_url": "https://thePaymentGateway.io"
        },
        {
            "address": "0x1EBAeF7Bee7B3a7B2EEfC72e86593Bf15ED37522",
            "currency": "eth",
            "amount": 0.1,
            "ipn_callback_url": "https://thePaymentGateway.io"
        },
        {
            "address": "0x1EBAeF7Bee7B3a7B2EEfC72e86593Bf15ED37522",
            "currency": "usdc",
            "amount": 1,
            "fiat_amount": 100,
            "fiat_currency": "usd",
            "ipn_callback_url": "https://thePaymentGateway.io"
        }
    ]
}'
```

I tried doing the below code, but what I could do is for single entry, the actual code is to take in array of "withdrawals" input to send to the endpoint: In my code I could not do the array with the Dictionary string.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can achieve sending the array of "withdrawals" to the endpoint?.

```cs
var client = new RestClient("https://api.thePaymentGateway.io/v1/payout");

var keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "address", "0x1EBAeF7Bee7B3a7B2EEfC72e86593Bf15ED37522"},
        { "currency", "usdttrc20"},
        { "amount", 200},
    };
//serialization using Newtonsoft JSON 
string JsonBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(keyValues);

var request = new RestRequest();
request.Method = Method.Post;
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer  {{token}}");
request.AddHeader("x-api-key", {{api-key}});
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", JsonBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: I usually do this kind of stuff with the help of postman. I create a new request past the curl code and get the restsharp code. It does not convert the json data into a serializable type but usually it works.

Comment: Why not create proper C# objects and post them? Let the compiler catch misspellings and missing properties

Comment: Your payment gateway likely has a C# SDK as a NuGet package that you can add to your solution, that will encapsulate all of these API calls for you. If it doesn't, but it has an OpenAPI specification, you can use Kiota to generate C# code to call the API. Both of these avenues should allow you to avoid crafting HTTP requests, but if you must, I'd strongly advise using the built-in .NET `HttpClient` over RestSharp - the latter forces you to write your code in a specific way while adding very little value, which makes it extremely difficult to switch it out at a later date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important bit is the structure you use to serialise the data and `Dictionary<string, string>` just won't work for you here.

You *could* use `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` but all those magic strings is going to bite you at some point. It would be better to use a purpose built DTO - `Withdrawal` and use `List<Withdrawal>`. Unfortunately that still doesn't match the structure of the curl request and you're going to need another DTO.

```
public class PayoutRequest
{
    [JsonPropertyName("ipn_callback_url")]
    public string IpnCallbackUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("withdrawals")]
    public List<Withdrawal> Withdrawals { get; set; }
}

public class Withdrawal
{
    [JsonPropertyName("address")]
    public string Address { get; set;}

    [JsonPropertyName("currency")]
    public string Currency { get; set;}

    [JsonPropertyName("amount")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set;}
}
```

Also, there's no need to manually serialise the data either, RestSharp will do that for you too.

**This code is untested and therefore may not be without bugs but you get the idea**

```
    var dto = new PayoutRequest
    {
        IpnCallbackUrl = "https://thePaymentGateway.io",
        Withdrawals = new List<Withdrawal>
        {
            new Withdrawal
            {
                Address = "0x1EBAeF7Bee7B3a7B2EEfC72e86593Bf15ED37522",
                Currency = "usdttrc20",
                Amount = 200m,
            }
        }
    };

    var request = new RestRequest();
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer  {token}");
    request.AddHeader("x-api-key", apiKey);
    request.AddJsonBody<PayoutRequest>(dto);

    var client = new RestClient("https://api.thePaymentGateway.io/v1/payout");
    RestResponse response = client.Post(request);
```

Of course, you'll have to add any additional properties you want to include in the request.

Comment: Phuzi thank you very much, it is clear, got it...